# TextArea on Blackberry: cursor does not advance for space

Tags: blackberry, java-me, textarea, lwuit, space

I have a BB app (written with j2me and lwuit). There are a lot of text fields (com.sun.lwuit.TextArea objects) in the app. When running it, if I type characters in the text fields, the cursor advances after each character, except for space. When I press space (no matter how many times), the cursor does not move. If I press space many times and then press another key (letter or whatever), the spaces are there... they appear correctly and the cursor advances after the last character. I hope I explained it clearly.

Anyone can tell what is wrong here? There is nothing special about the TextArea objects... I just create them then set a hint and a max size, that's it.

Thanks a lot,

Silviu

Comment: Debugging might be helpful, check if `getCursorX()` returns different values on each `keyPressed(keyCode)`.

Comment: It is visually annoying and it is not the expected behaviour. You could use lwuit source instead of library and debug.